# How do I implement lookahead and non lookahead in the same regex statement?

Tags: regex, parsing

How do I implement both a lookahead (without replacement), and a non-lookahead in the same regex statement?

I want to split up a sentence such as:

```
"ad1 cow run sick ag2 4 8 6 9 crap2 ag lag pag arg2 8 6 5"
```

into

```
ad1 cow run sick
ag2 4 8 6 9
crap2 ag lag pag
arg2 8 6 5
```

Here is the statement that almost gets me there with a lookahead:

```
"(?=\\s\\w\\w*\\d)"
```

That is, it looks for a space, a character in the string, any number of characters following that, and then it is followed by a digit. Here Is what I get with that:

```
ad1 cow run sick
 ag2 4 8 6 9
 crap2 ag lag pag
 arg2 8 6 5
```

Notice the spaces there still since I had a lookahead. How do I remove those spaces as well in the same regex statement?

Comment: Put it out of the lookahead: `"\\s+(?=\\w+\\d)"`. This way, the whitespaces will get consumed and thus removed when splitting.

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead at all? It seems like you should just be using a normal pattern match.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm still learning the difference between regex and pattern match. If I pattern match, does it still separate the string?

Comment: A pattern match returns the parts of the string that match the pattern. If you match multiple times, it splits up the string.

Comment: So, [did it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549470/3832970) in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use your pattern as a match (note that `\\w\\w*` can be written as`\\w+`

```
\\w+\\d.*?(?=\\s\\w+\\d|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\\w+\\d` Match 1+ word chars and a digit
- `.*?` Match as least as possible characters
- `(?=` Positive lookeahd

  - `\\s\\w+\\d` match a whitespace char, 1+ word chars and a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/drJoLF/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/eReSkV)

Java example

```
String regex = "\\w+\\d.*?(?=\\s\\w+\\d|$)";
String string = "ad1 cow run sick ag2 4 8 6 9 crap2 ag lag pag arg2 8 6 5\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
ad1 cow run sick
ag2 4 8 6 9
crap2 ag lag pag
arg2 8 6 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a little outside of the question, but do you by chance know what implementation I would use this pattern match to get the strings back in java? I am currently just putting the string in str.split() method. I see pattern matching with java in a google search, But I'm only seeing it checking if a pattern matches, not returning a split, in my basic search.

Comment: @rickster26ter1 I have added a Java example to get the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the whitespace matching pattern out of the lookahead:

```
"\\s+(?=\\w+\\d)"
```

This way, the whitespaces will get consumed and thus removed during splitting.

*Details*

- `\s+`  - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\w+\d)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with one or more word chars and then a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nevfPB/1).